# Activity stack state

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, state

I'm currently adding the option to start my app from another app.
The app will look and behave differently when started from another app.
The entry point activity is passed a different intent action and some extras. 
I need to save those extras for other activities but I cannot save them in the app,
Because that will affect the app when launched from the launcher.
The only solution I can think of is to pass the extras for each new activity:
intent.putExtras(getIntent());
And so maintain a state for the current stack.
Is there a better way?
Thanks,
Sharon.

Comment: use setter and getter. Once values is stored in that, then you can call anywhere in your app.

Comment: But what's wrong with passing extras in the intent to other activities?

Comment: TechEnd, setter and getter in the app (extending class)? I understand that the same app instance is used for both stacks.
Aleks G, I was hoping to solve this globally.

Answer (score 1):

```
Because that will affect the app when launched from the launcher.
```

I don't think so, when the app is launched from the launcher, the intent you get via `getIntent()` contains the action of `"android.intent.action.MAIN"`. therefore, you can run a check to see if it's launched from the launcher or another app.
You can then restore the values contained in extras(if some other app started it) in a single sharedpreference xml file so that all other activities can access them conveniently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I can detect the launch mode at entry point.
The problem is that the pref. file is shared.
For example, if the user starts the app from the launcher
Then starts it from another app and then goes back to the one started from the launcher,
The app started from the launcher will behave like the one started from another app.

Comment: @sharon Actually, you can save the values in a different sharedPreference xml file. One app can have several sharedPreference xml files. Detecting how the app is launched and load values from the corresponding xml file.

Comment: I will still need to pass a parameter to each activity, indicating which pref. file to use according to the launch mode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a different way.
Whenever the application is launched, the previously launched activity is sent an event.
The stack is then redirected to a special activity that notifies the user that the app was launched elsewhere.
This activity has a button to relaunch the app.
This way the app cannot run in parallel.
Not sure it's the best solution but it works and it prevents undesirable app state.
Sharon.